# How to specify allowed characters in keyboard?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms, data-entry

I want to create a page for pin entry for both, android and iOS platforms. `Numeric` specification in `Keyboard` property is close to my needs. I can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086881/restricting-input-length-and-characters-for-entry-field-in-xamarin-forms) to restrict allowed characters and overall length. However I need to get rid of the dot character on the keyboard. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the dot from the soft keyboard.

Using the solution you linked and `Keyboard="Numeric"`, you can use the same `TextChanged` event that restricts entry text size to restrict the '.'.

Example:

```cs
public void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var e = sender as Entry;
    string val = e.Text;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (MaxLength > 0 && val.Length > MaxLength)
    {
        val = val.Remove(val.Length - 1);
    }

    if (val.Contains("."))
    {
        val.Replace(".", string.Empty);    
    }
    e.Text = val;
}
```

**Other option** would be creating a `Grid` for the PIN. And show the PIN in a `Label` instead of and `Entry` to avoid pasting.

Comment: I asked how to remove a character from the keyboard, not how to restrict input.

Comment: Even if you could remove it from the keyboard you need to protect again copy/paste the dot.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please tell me what you think. And please update your answer because "How to specify allowed characters in entry?" isn't the same as "remove a character from the keyboard, not how to restrict input."